# 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME: no identity found

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, code-signing

I need to sign the code of an app I'm trying to submit to App Store through terminal:

```
codesign -f -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME' --entitlements "APPNAME.entitlements" "/AppPath/APPNAME.app"
```

but I'm getting the error `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME: no identity found` for all `DEVELOPER NAME` I try. I have no idea of what to fill in it.

What should I fill in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘Developer name’ is your personal name or company name, depending on whether you have a personal or organisation developer program membership respectively. You're also missing the Team ID from the string, which in the end should look something like this:

> 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: John Appleseed (XXXXXXXXXX)

You can find your developer name and Team ID in Keychain Access. Search for "developer" and find one of your certificates. The green section is your developer name, and the blue section is your Team ID.

[image]